# Display number of members of each group in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, list, group-by, yii2

In my MySql table I have groups defined by id's like this:

group 1 - 01
group 2 - 02
group 3 - 03

Those groups have subgroups:

01 group has subgroups : 011, 013, 014...

Members are part of each subgroup. For example John is member of 011 subgroup.

I need to count all member of each group ( and therefore its subgroups ) and display it next to group name like this:

Group 01 : 100 members
Group 02 : 45 member
Group 03 : 73 members

I am using, html, php, mysql and yii2 php framework.

Using yii2 active record, I am counting members of group 01 like this:

```
<?= Club::find()->where(['like', 'group_id', '01%', false])->count() ?>
```

This code is executing this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `club` WHERE `group_id` LIKE '01%'
```

What is the most optimal way of doing this task? I need to display list with count of all group members. I do not think that optimal way is to run this query for each group and hard code that in page.

Any help, mysql, php, yii2... whatever?

Comment: Still struggling? Consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Do you have a subgroup table?

Comment: No, groups are stored in strict hierarchy. Their Id's represent that hierarchy. For example group one ( parent level ) has id 01000, children of that ( subgroups ) are : 01100, 01200, 01300... And those children have their children, for example, child 01100 has children: 01110, 01120...

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Yi, but the mysql statement you need is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `club` 
GROUP BY substr(group_id, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest try running this code and seeing if it matches what you are after:

```
SELECT `group_id`, Count(`group_id`) AS `Count of group_id` FROM `club` GROUP BY `group_id`
```

Hopefully, it will return a table of group_id with a count for each.

Update - if the group_id column contains 011, 012 etc. instead of 01, 02, 03 then use the substr or left function as the group by argument:

```
SELECT `group_id`, Count(`group_id`) AS `Count of group_id` FROM `club` GROUP BY Left(`group_id`,2)
```

Comment: This will return me associative array of counts. How would I modify this query to select group name from related table called group ? group.id = club.group_id and group table have column called "name". Also how to display this in html list ? name + count

Answer (score 0):

You could select everything out and perform the count in PHP like..

```
 foreach($results as $result){
     $counts[substr($result['group_id'],0,2)]++;
 }
```

Assumes that the first 2 digits of your sub groups are always the group id.